# Matlab Plot XTickLabel valid strings

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a plot:

```
x = [0 1 2 3];
y = [0 0 1 1];

plot (x, y, 'k');
```

I want to use labels at X-axis, and it works:

```
set(gca,'XTick',[0:3]) % This automatically sets 
labels = ['0'; 'T'; 'T'; '1';];
set(gca,'XTickLabel',labels)
```

However, when I change `T` to `T0`. It doesn't work.

**Q1:** What are the valid strings of `XTickLabel`?

**Q2:** How can I use strings like T0, T1. Or is that possible to use characters with subindex like $A_2$ in latex format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set strings of different lengths, you need to use cell arrays, i.e.

```
labels = {'0','T','T0','somethingCompletelyDifferent'}
```

will work.

If you want to use Latex to format tick labels, you'll need to [download a function from the Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986).